# Sortable bind an on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a sortable element of `div`

```
<div class="question-constructor multiple-choice-problem">
<label for="textbox" class="question-label"> #. Edit this to define question: </label>
   <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-1" class="question-radio" style="float:left;">
   <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-2" class="question-radio" style="float:left;">
   <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-3" class="question-radio" style="float:left;">
   <input type="radio" name="test" id="option-1-4" class="question-radio" style="float:left;">
</div>
```

This `div`s are draggable then are dropped to the sortable. Here is the `div` where they drop the draggable:

`<div id="preview" ></div>`

Here is my sortable JS:

```
var sortableIn = 0;
$('#preview').sortable({
     receive: function(event, ui) {             
        sortableIn = 1;
        $(ui.item).addClass('editable');
     },
     placeholder: 'ph',
     over: function(event, ui) { sortableIn = 1; },
     out: function(event, ui) { sortableIn = 0; },
     start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(ui.helper).addClass('on-sort');
     },
     beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            if (sortableIn == 0) { 
                ui.item.remove(); 
            }
     },
     stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).find('.on-sort').removeClass("on-sort");
     }
});
```

What I want to do is create an `onclick` even to the sortable items specificaly. I tried using this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#preview ', function() {
        console.log('clickable');
    });
});
```

But when I clicked the sortable items It clicks every thing. I want to change the text of the `label` on the sortable div where I specifically clicked.

For example:

1. I dragged `.question-constructor` `div` 3 times to the `#preview` div. (This will make the `#preview` sortable div have 3 items)
2. When I click the **2nd item** in the sortable div, I want to change the text label on it to another value( only on this item ).

How can I do this?

If my question is unclear please comment below and I will respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use the on click event but over the clicked item:

```
$(".question-label").on("click", function (e) {
    $(e.target).text('I am changed');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBXkT/